# When I make my screen smaller, my input are all getting messed up

Tags: flexbox, accessibility, media, viewport

When I shrink my screen, my inputs are all spilling over my container. I tried to put in display block, tried to flex wrap it. Looked at other websites... but somehow my content spills over my container.

```
  .travel-container {
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    width: 50vw;
    min-height: 60vh;
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;

}

@media (max-width: 40rem) {   
    .travel-container > * {
        display: block;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to render your example code interactive, so we can more easily reproduce the issue?

Comment: Which were your intentions when adding the tag `accessibility`. Do you have any specific question about it?